Code to compare contents of two .xlsx file
I have below code to compare files inside zip folder. The code works fine for .csv, .xml. I have problem with .xlsx. The zip folder has .xlsx file which is system generated. By naked eye the content of excel look same but the Get-Content and Compare-Object identify them as different. The code works fine when I copy same file and compare. Any help is appreciated. Thanks
[string]$EventID1 = Read-Host -Prompt "Input ID-1"
[string]$EventID2 = Read-Host -Prompt "Input ID-2"
 
# Function to compare the contents of files inside zip folders
function Compare-ZipContents {
    param (
        [string]$zipFile1,
        [string]$zipFile2
    )
    $zip1 = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile1)
    $zip2 = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile2)

    $xmlFilePath1 = $zip1.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.xml" }
    $xmlFilePath2 = $zip2.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.xml" }

    $csvFiles1 = $zip1.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.csv" }
    $csvFiles2 = $zip2.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.csv" }
 
    $excelFiles1 = $zip1.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.xlsx" -or $_.Name -like "*.xls" }
    $excelFiles2 = $zip2.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.xlsx" -or $_.Name -like "*.xls" }
 
    foreach ($xml1 in $xmlFilePath1) {
        foreach ($xml2 in $xmlFilePath2) {
            $stream1 = $xml1.Open()
            $stream2 = $xml2.Open()
            $reader1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream1)
            $reader2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream2)
            $content1 = $reader1.ReadToEnd()
            $content2 = $reader2.ReadToEnd()
            if ($content1 -eq $content2) {
                Write-Output "$($xml1.Name) and $($xml2.Name) are identical."
            }
            Else { Write-Output "$($xml1.Name) and $($xml2.Name) are different."}
            $reader1.Close()
            $reader2.Close()
            $stream1.Close()
            $stream2.Close()
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($csv1 in $csvFiles1) {
        foreach ($csv2 in $csvFiles2) {
            $stream1 = $csv1.Open()
            $stream2 = $csv2.Open()
            $reader1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream1)
            $reader2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream2)
            $content1 = $reader1.ReadToEnd()
            $content2 = $reader2.ReadToEnd()
            if ($content1 -eq $content2) {
                Write-Output "$($csv1.Name) and $($csv2.Name) are identical."
            }
            Else { Write-Output "$($csv1.Name) and $($csv2.Name) are different."}
            $reader1.Close()
            $reader2.Close()
            $stream1.Close()
            $stream2.Close()
        }
    }
 
    foreach ($excel1 in $excelFiles1) {
        foreach ($excel2 in $excelFiles2) {
            $stream1 = $excel1.Open()
            $stream2 = $excel2.Open()
            $reader1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream1)
            $reader2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream2)
            $content1 = $reader1.ReadToEnd()
            $content2 = $reader2.ReadToEnd()
            if ($content1 -eq $content2) {
                Write-Output "$($excel1.Name) and $($excel2.Name) are identical."
            }
            Else {Write-Output "$($excel1.Name) and $($excel2.Name) are different."}
            $reader1.Close()
            $reader2.Close()
            $stream1.Close()
            $stream2.Close()

        }
    }
 
    $zip1.Dispose()
    $zip2.Dispose()
}
 
# Path
$zipFile1 = "Address 1"
$zipFile2 = "Address 2"
Compare-ZipContents -zipFile1 $zipFile1 -zipFile2 $zipFile2


Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, you have a function Compare-ExcelContent (never called), and calling unknown Compare-ZipContents…

@JosefZ i have added the whole instead of snippets. Apologies for the partial code.

You want to compare XLSX files, and you do Compare-ZipContents ??   Please proof-read your own question!

The zip is system generated which may contain xlsx, csv or xml. What i am trying to do is compare the zip and it's contents. The xlsx generated inside the zip is a error log. When comparing the xlsx in both zip along with others (csv , xml), xlsx is identified as different even though they appear same. I hope i make more sense now. @Luuk

@Luuk I get your question. That was mistake from my end. Updated question.

A XLSX file is also a ZIP file. (see: How to open and view the XML structure of an Excel file?)  So you need to do some research on: compare XLSX files, because that question has been asked before

import-excel module?

@js2010: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.6

This code uses much of what you posted in the question. It will compare the archive file's Crc32 values for the files that are in both archives. It needs testing and comment based help added.
# Function to compare the contents of files inside zip folders
function Compare-Archive {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Archive1
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Archive2
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]] $Extension
    )
    $re = '^.*(' + ($Extension -join '|') + ')$'

    $Zip1 = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead((Convert-Path -Path $Archive1))
    $Zip2 = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead((Convert-Path -Path $Archive2))

    $FilePath1 = $zip1.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $re }
    $FilePath2 = $zip2.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $re }

    $AllFiles = (@($FilePath1.fullname) + @($FilePath2.FullName)) | Sort-Object -Unique

    foreach ($File in $AllFiles) {
        if ($File -notin $FilePath1.FullName) {
            Write-Warning "File $($File) is not in Archive1"
        }
        if ($File -notin $FilePath2.FullName) {
            Write-Warning "File $($File) is not in Archive2"
        }
    }

    $FilesToCompare = ((@($FilePath1.FullName) + @($FilePath2.FullName)) | Group-Object -NoElement | Where-Object Count -gt 1).Name

    foreach ($File in $FilesToCompare) {
        $File1 = $FilePath1 | Where-Object { $_.FullName -ceq $File }
        $File2 = $FilePath2 | Where-Object { $_.FullName -ceq $File }

        if ($File1.Crc32 -ne $File2.Crc32) {
            Write-Output [pscustomobject]@{
                FileName = $File
                File1Crc32 = $File1.Crc32
                File2Crc32 = $File1.Crc32
            }
        }
    }

    $zip1.Dispose()
    $zip2.Dispose()
}

# Compare-Archive -Archive1 'f1.zip' -Archive2 'f1notin2.zip'


My test fails (using one zipfile name abc1.zip with only 1 file in it names abc1.clsx). PS D:\TEMP> Compare-Archive -Archive1 '.\abc1.zip' -Archive2 '.\abc1.zip'
WARNING: File ABC1.xlsxABC1.xlsx is not in Archive1
WARNING: File ABC1.xlsxABC1.xlsx is not in Archive2

@Luuk, I do not know how that output would be generated. I do not see any place where the filename is put together twice. What is the output of your $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()?

I will check later, probably tomorrow, or even after that.. so do not hurry

@Luuk, thank you for finding this issue. It only occurs when the first archive contains only one (1) file. Needs more testing as advertized. Answer is edited. Please give it a try when you can. Thanks.

The problem with comparing Excel files using CRC or other file hashes is that it will only work if the files are exact copies of each other.  As soon as you open and save one of the files even without interacting at all with a spreadsheet or modifying it any way, there are still guids and other unseen values that change in the internal xml files which will influence the hash generated.  If the poster is trying to compare zip files generated at different times, like with some snapshot tool for example, even if the data contents generated are identical, the CRC/hash will still be different.

@Daniel, I agree that can be a problem. Given two (2) .xlsx files, what tool would you use to compare the content?

The ImportExcel module that js2010 posted has a Compare-Worksheet cmdlet that may work.  You may have to loop through the available worksheets in each excel file separately, or not.  I haven't used it or read the help for it, but my experience when using other functionality in the package has been 5 star

My other thought was, and no idea if this will compare thoroughly enough, would be to open each excel file package same as the zip and then compare all of the xml worksheet files in xl\worksheets and xl\sharedStrings.xml with those in the other zip/excel file the same way as in the original post comparing the byte streams or your CRC method.  Stay away from comparing workbook.xml as this definitely has uids that are different but I don't think it really needs to be considered in the compare AFAIK.  I think comparing just these worksheet files and the sharedStrings would be enough to compare

Scratch that.  The sheet xml files also have uids that may change.  Seems like the compare will have to be more involved, possibly doing a replace to remove the uids first before comparing

@Daniel, the ImportExcel module Compare-Worksheet looks interesting. But, it seems to be oriented toward worksheets designed with the first row as column header names. It does not appear to be a comparison of -any- worksheet. Also, it is not clear if it checks things like font, font size, colors, borders, etc... I have used ImportExcel before and it is a capable tool.
